# if statement в принятии сообщений

Tags: java, сокет, if

Принимаю сообщения с сервера.
Поставила следующее условие.

```
                    String fromServer = in.readLine();
                    System.out.println("From server: " + fromServer);
                    if(fromServer.equals("Correct!")){
                    String fromServerStar = in.readLine();
                    System.out.println("From server: " + fromServerStar);
                    }else if(fromServer.equals("Correct!") && fromServer.equals("Correct!")){
                        String from = in.readLine();
                        System.out.println("From server: " + from);
                        String fromServerStar = in.readLine();
                        System.out.println("From server: " + fromServerStar);
                    }
```

Во втором `if statement` не знаю как задать условие.

Получается я хочу условие специально для того, чтобы выполнить действия, если я получила в консоле 2 раза подряд `correct`

```
From server: Correct!
From server: Correct!
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

может так? :

```
       String fromServer = in.readLine();
         System.out.println("From server: " + fromServer);
         if(fromServer.equals("Correct!")){
                String fromServerStar = in.readLine();


                if(fromServerStar.equals("Correct!")){
                    String from = in.readLine();
                    System.out.println("From server: " + from);
                    String THISfromServerStar = in.readLine();
                    System.out.println("From server: " + THISfromServerStar);
                 }
                 else
                    System.out.println("From server: " + fromServerStar);
          }
```

Comment: Да, я думала об этом. Тогда получается, что в начале обрабатывается первое if statement => затем то, которое внутри видит эту строчку с correct  и начинает обрабатывать тоже. А мне уже не надо чтобы оно было задействовано.

Comment: я в коде подправил, так? Или я не понял комментария...

Comment: Да, спасибо. разобралась)